# Sharepoint 2013 - Create a folder icon

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, folder, file-icons

I don't want to replace the folder icon within the template.

I do want to see if there is a workaround which will allow me to add an icon in a calculated field or something. Has anyone done this - and how much trouble is it?

[image]

Something like this but image alongside a folder in the view

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about how you envision it working?

Comment: I have updated with a graphic to demonstrate the sort of thing I want to achieve with a folder.

Comment: Help me understand please. Are you looking to have the folder icon be in the field, similar to how the PDF icon is, or are you looking to have this kind of metadata on the folder type?

Comment: No - a custom image - not the folder icon or any other system icon

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to display image using formula then in the calculated column SharePoint throws error or just displays the text in the column instead of the button

Try with SharePoint designer.
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jay/2013/06/17/how-to-display-images-in-a-calculated-column-of-a-sharepoint-list/

Comment: This falls short of what I need. I need more than two options which is all I will get from this script. I need 6 choices and I have not been able to find a suitable script that will work in a document library.